# math.sin() not returning proper value

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Hello I have an equation I am trying to calculate using python. Where
The desired output I am looking for is `1.71528`

Below I have my current code with all of the current values d should equal 100 and theta should equal 60.

```
import math

m = 0.065
g = 9.8
print("Input the distance to professor")
d = 100 # float(input())
k = 25
print("Now input the value for theta")
theta = 60 # float(input())

x = math.sqrt(m*g*d/k*math.sin(2 * theta))
print(x, 'meters')
```

The output I get when I run this code is `1.2163047715819324 meters`

I think my issue is something with math.sin any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: I don't know if that is the actual problem but trig functions in almost every programming language take radians as inputs (2 * pi radians is one circle) instead of degrees. You can convert using `math.radians`.

Comment: What output you want.

Comment: I want x to equal = 1.71528

Comment: @AlexanderMurdock have look at my answer below

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sin equation in python keeps returning the wrong answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870697/sin-equation-in-python-keeps-returning-the-wrong-answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to theta to radians and put brackets around the denominator.

```
x = math.sqrt(m*g*d/(k*math.sin(2 * math.radians(theta))))
print(f"{x:.5f} meters")
```

Will result in

```
Input the distance to professor
100
Now input the value for theta
60
1.71528 meters
```

Comment: That's correct but don't make code-only answer, explain

Comment: you can suggest `x = round(x, 5)` to get expected `1.71528`

Comment: @azro the formatting for the print statement would just have to be adapted for printing with less decimal places